# run node scheduler between 9am and 5pm - monday to friday

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, cron, scheduler

I have a simple node.js parser that has to push data to a remote server during work hours only and sleep for the rest of the time.

Looking at the available modules, schedule and node-cron (https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) seems to do part of my requirement.

I am using the PM2 module to restart the process, when it goes down

Here is what I have so far in coffee script:

```
runParser = (callback) ->
  #...
  console.log 'waking up parser...'
  parseAll()
  return

_jobs = [ {
  name: 'Start parser'
  cronTime: '00 34 16 * * 1-5'
  onTick: runParser
  start: true
  id: 'parsedbf'
  #timeZone: 'Europe/London'
} ]

_cronJobs = {}
schedule = ->
  _jobs.map (job) ->
    _cronJobs[job.id] = new cronJob(job)
    console.log util.format('%s cronjob scheduled at %s on timezone', job.name, job.cronTime)
    return
  return

run = ->
  start = moment('08:30','HH:mm').valueOf()
  now = moment().valueOf()
  end =  moment('18:00','HH:mm').valueOf()
  if start < now and now < end
    runParser()
  else
    schedule(console.info 'scheduler started...')

run(console.info 'sync code statrted after a hard reboot...')
```

my question, how do i change the script so that at 18:30 the parser is just idle?

should i use schedule.js (http://bunkat.github.io/schedule/index.html) how do i modify the code for this?

any advice much appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run this in cron? You have the question tagged for cron which refers to the unix utility, it was made to do this sort of thing. You could use a combination of cron and `forever`: one call starts it in the am and another stops the script in the evening but it runs continuously otherwise.

Comment: actually, yes, i can just have two cron jobs, on to start the pm2 module in the morning and one to shut it down in the evening. thanks i should keep it simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just run this in cron? You have the question tagged for cron which refers to the unix utility, it was made to do this sort of thing. You could use a combination of cron and [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever): one call starts it in the am and another stops the script in the evening but it runs continuously otherwise.